# Where is the "Use ".deploy" file extension" option in visual studio 2017

Tags: deployment, configuration, visual-studio-2017

Following from this webpage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx

which states:

> you can disable this option by clearing the Use ".deploy" file
>   extension option on the Publish Options Dialog Box,

Where is the "Use .deploy file extension" option in VS 2017? It's not in the Publish Options Dialog Box anymore. HELP

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project. Choose *Properties*. From there switch to the *Publish* tab, click *Options...* and switch to the *Deployment* tab.
[image: screen shot]