# How to globally config a VSTO Excel AddIn?

Tags: c#, excel, deployment, configuration, vsto

I have a VSTO Excel addin, which works properly. Only facing some issues regarding deployment. The addin is deployed (native publish option in VS2019) on an SMB-Share. Both the installation path and the publish path is the path to the certain SMB-Share.

From this share everybody can install the addin via double click the .vsto-file. However, in the Application Files folder I connot find the config-file.

The bin/release folder on my machine, after building the application, looks like this:

```
|   app.config
|   itextsharp.dll
|   itextsharp.xml
|   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll
|   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
|   Newtonsoft.Json.xml
|   MyAppName.dll
|   MyAppName.dll.config
|   MyAppName.dll.manifest
|   MyAppName.pdb
|   MyAppName.vsto
|   
\---Properties
        Settings.Designer.cs
        Settings.settings
```

In the MyAppName.dll.config there are some global configs, which applies to all users using this addin. I want to be able, to change this config after deployment.

However, if I deploy it to the SMB share, it looks like this:

```
itextsharp.dll.deploy
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll.deploy
Newtonsoft.Json.dll.deploy
MyAppName.dll.config.deploy
MyAppName.dll.deploy
MyAppName.dll.manifest
MyAppName.vsto
```

How can I change the configuration for every client?

BR Jonas

Comment: How may I change that? However, there is a MyAppName.dll.config.deploy, but what's the .deploy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267176/9059424

Comment: i stand corrected https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-set-up-configuration-information-for-an-office-solution?view=vs-2019

Comment: That looks fine, how do I bind and access that newly built file to my application?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no publishing option to aviod the .deploy extension

[image]

Comment: SO is an English site.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the local installation. I just wanted to show, that there are options missing,,,

Answer (score 0):

The file is included to the ClickOnce installer:

> MyAppName.dll.config.deploy

If you need to change any file from the deployment package you can use the `Mage.exe` or `MageUI.exe` utility to re-deploy the application/add-in. Read more about that in the [Walkthrough: Manually deploy a ClickOnce application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019) article in MSDN.

Comment: Is there no way to just deploy via VS? How is the "normal" common way to deploy VSTO add ins? All tutorials and docs from MSDN I found are obsolete

Comment: So please, could you give me some advise where to find a answer to my question?